# Typescript generic constraints on type parameters class

Tags: typescript, type-constraints

How can you put a constraint on a TypeScript type parameter. In c# you can use the construct `{ where T:class}`?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics-generic-constraints)

Comment: This seems like a valid question to me and the answer is exactly what people coming from .NET / Java etc. expect to have in TypeScript. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Agree with @Alexei. No idea why this was closed as a request for an off-site resource (unanimously, at that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Typescript support constraints on type parameters like c# { where T:class}.

Yes. Syntax is of the form `<T extends SomeClass>` instead of `<T>`

## Example

```
interface Foo{
    foo: number;
}

function foo<T extends Foo>(foo:T){
    console.log(foo.foo);
}

foo({foo:123}); // okay
foo({foo:'123'}); // Error
```

Note that types in typescript are structural ([why](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)) which means that classes and interfaces are handled the same way as far as the generic constraint is concerned.

Comment: Thanks Basarat for your answer, seen your collection and online resource before which are very helpful and thanks again for your help, most of classes derived from one class Entity, your suggestion will save me lots of time.